# Adding item in ListView OnClick of a Button

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I know this question has been floating all over the place, however I am unable to work this through even after going through all the posts and trying to understand. I am very new to developing apps in Android, so I definitely would need a lot of assistance. Anyways, I found some coding online that basically created a listview (the way I wanted with the layouts) and you could add items to the listview. Here's the code -

```
 ListView lv;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> feedList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_out);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CheckList);

    feedList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("item", "Item");
    map.put("qty", "Qty");
    map.put("tax", "Tax");
    map.put("total", "Total");
    feedList.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, feedList, R.layout.list_view_customs, new String[]{"item", "qty", "tax", "total"}, new int[]{R.id.textViewItem, R.id.textViewQty, R.id.textViewTax, R.id.textViewTotal});
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

As you can see that items are being added to the arraylist through the implementation of hashmaps and then the adapter is taking in the data arraylist to create a list view - which is set by the setAdapter functionality.

So, now since I wanted to populate the listview through a button click, I thought that this might work:

```
ListView lv;
Button addBanana;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> feedList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_out);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CheckList);
    addBanana = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddItem);

    feedList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("item", "Item");
    map.put("qty", "Qty");
    map.put("tax", "Tax");
    map.put("total", "Total");
    feedList.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, feedList, R.layout.list_view_customs, new String[]{"item", "qty", "tax", "total"}, new int[]{R.id.textViewItem, R.id.textViewQty, R.id.textViewTax, R.id.textViewTotal});
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        addBanana.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         map.put("item", "Banana");
         map.put("qty", "1");
         map.put("tax", "0.13");
         map.put("total", "1.13");
         feedList.add(map);
         simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
  }
```

It builds up perfectly. But when I try to go to this activity by clicking a button (which is in the main activity), the screen turns dark and says to quit .. So, I am not sure what is wrong with this approach. I know there is definitely something wrong with the way I am handling the adapters ... So, any feedbacks would be nice.. Thanks a lot!

Also, if you need the XML's, please let me know!

Again, sorry to relist the question again, I am in desperate need for help..

Comment: Is there an error trace in the log cat? What says to quit?

Comment: Have you set proper Intent to go to this activity?

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work for `SimpleAdapter`. Do you see a red line there?

Comment: I am not sure if notifyDataSetChanged() works or not, however I don't see a red line ..

Comment: Post your LogCat and xml file please.

Comment: Here's a link to the logcat 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqjiz638rtll3lr/problem.png?dl=0

Comment: You have a NullPointerException ( i guess `addBanana` is null), post your *activity_check_out.xml*

Comment: Here's a link to the XML's

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yebxnx465zs9z8g/AABXOaKA_sE0xzusW_0bYxCLa?dl=0

Comment: *activity_check_out.xml* don't have a button with *AddItem* as id, so when you call `addBanana = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddItem);` you have a **null** as result which cause the NullPointerException when you try to use  `addBanana`  button. So, you need to add your button inside *activity_check_out.xml*

Comment: I actually thought I was calling the button from list_view_customs.xml .. let me add in a button and will let you know .. Thank You :) !

Comment: Well adding a button did fix the problem, but since the actual layout of the listview is shown through list_view_customs.xml, I won't be able to use the button ...

Comment: i didn't understand... what you mean by "I won't be able to use the button"? click not working?

Comment: sorry, discard what I mentioned - I was thinking differently .. Thank You so much! That worked !